# Соответствует ли решение заданию?

Tags: css-animation

1) Написать анимацию без использования animate.css и wow.js для фотографии

- Элемент должен быть изначально скрыт
- Он должен появиться с задержкой в 0.4 секунды
- Должен выехать снизу и развернуться на 90 градусов по оси Y
- Длительность анимации 1 секунда

  **Это решение**

  ```
   @keyframes animate
      0%
       visibility: hidden
       opacity: 0
       transform: translateY(100%)

       100%
        visibility: visible
        opacity: 1
        transform: translateY(-10%)
        transform: rotateY(90deg)

      .animate
        animation-name: animate
        animation-delay: 0.4s
        animation-duration:  1s
  ```

Такое решение правильно(по-моему точно неправильно)? Как правильнее можно написать этот код?

Comment: Какое-то расплывчатое задание. Да и трудно представить для чего нужна подобная анимация. Возможно имелось ввиду что-нибудь подобное: https://jsfiddle.net/epqyxu7o/ ?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex  Какое-то расплывчатое задание - Также думаю.Типа вот такое: <div class="img animate" ><img src="#" alt=""></div>. К этому блоку надо применять все эти задании. Длительность анимации если 1 секунда, то как можно успеть увидеть что оно скрыто, потом снизу вверх появляется с задержкой.